# Is it possible to include the method name for an endpoint through Swashbuckle?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

So I'm trying to add API documentation for a set of old REST endpoints created through .NET Web API.  Someone suggested that I try using Swashbuckle to generate documentation off the existing endpoints, which sort of works.

My issue is that these endpoints have names that provide some context and Swashbuckle only seems to pick up the controller and not the actual method name.  For example, I have the following endpoint:

```
public class CatalogAvailabilityController
{
    public List<string> GetSupportedCatalogsForCountry([FromUri] string countryCode)
    {
        //--return supported catalogs
    }
}
```

In this case, the generated Swagger outputs something like the following:

[image]

Basically, it only includes the controller name (CatalogAvailability) in the URL, but I want it to have the "GetSupportedCatalogsForCountry" in the URL as well.  Is there a way to have Swashbuckle generate it like this or do I need to resort to going back and creating the Swagger myself?

And yes, ideally, it probably shouldn't be setup like this and it should be more RESTful, but it's an older legacy system which would take a substantial effort to refactor, so I thought I'd ask first.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: isnt it doing that because that is the endpoint defined by that method? like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection)?
So that GET /api/catalogAvailability?countryCode=gb would route to `GetSupportedCatalogsForCountry`?

Comment: @LewisTaylor If the only method in the controller is GetSupportedCatalogsForCountry, then yes, it would route to that method since it's the only GET.  However, I have multiple GET methods.  I only included the one in this question to make it simpler

Comment: What do the other method look like in the controller / swagger? is it doing the routing just based on the [method parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection#action-selection)?

Comment: Something like:

`public List<string> GetSupportedCatalogsForLanguage([FromUri] string languageCode)`

Comment: i think that swagger might be correct. if you expand the box in swagger does it show the different query parameters for multiple methods in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Add **Attributes** to your action and Route attributes to your controller.

```
public class CatalogAvailabilityController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public List<string> GetSupportedCatalogsForCountry([FromUri] string countryCode)
    {
        //--return supported catalogs
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following crossminder answer:

```
public class CatalogAvailabilityController
{
    [HttpGet("GetSupportedCatalogsForCountry")]
    public List<string> GetSupportedCatalogsForCountry([FromUri] string countryCode)
    {
         //--return supported catalogs
    }
}
```